# Fatal Python error: _PyMainInterpreterConfig_Read: memory allocation failed

Tags: osx, python3

I installed python3 on my macos using brew. Then I created virtual environment using `python3 -m venv env`. I have installed all my requirements in the virtualenv. Now when i try to run pytest. It gives me following error

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: _PyMainInterpreterConfig_Read: memory allocation failed
ValueError: character U+7273752f is not in range [U+0000; U+10ffff]

Current thread 0x0000000115b015c0 (most recent call first):
```

I am running pytest using command

```
py.test  -s tests/blueprints/test_blueprint.py::TestCRUD::test_blueprint_without_requried_fields
```

and the path to test case is correct

Comment: if i use virtualenv to set environment, then also I get same error. I have tried setting PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME to my env path. But that only removes first three lines of error

Comment: virtualenv creating also sends the same error
```virtualenv -p `which python3.7`  env```

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting a long outstanding python bug here, see the following references:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36657523/python-3-3-cant-install-packages-in-a-virtualenv
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459384/unicode-character-not-in-range-when-calling-locale-strxfrm
- https://bugs.python.org/issue23195

I added this as an answer, as this seems to be convoluted manifestation of the issue.